# Remove previous installation on WiX

Tags: .net, wix, installation, wix3.6

I have a product distributed on a website. Every time a user downloads this file, I compile everything again with WiX. In each build, the version doesn't change, but some files do.

**Question**
How to force the installer to uninstall my software, no matter the version, before it begins the installation itself?

**EDITED**
I already tried this:

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="Erro Message." />
```

Comment: Do you have an Upgrade code mentioned in the original installer?

Comment: @isaiah4110 I updated the post, take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the product ID to *, this will ensure that a unique GUID is generated during the MSI compilation.

Then add the following :

```
<Property Id="OLDVersion" Secure="yes" /> 
<Upgrade Id="YOUR_GUID">      
     <UpgradeVersion
            Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="99.0.0.0"
            Property="OLDVersion"
            IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" /> 
</Upgrade>
```

Under InstallExecuteSequence add:

```
<RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
```

This should take care of uninstalling the previously installed versions.

> Make sure that the Upgrade GUID which you are using is common across all the versions of your MSI.

Check this [LINK](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_upgradeversion.htm)

Comment: This works fine, but the old version property must be public, so the name must be uppercase, for example `OLDVERSION`.

Comment: Do I need to remove the MajorUpgrade tag ?

Comment: ok, MajorUpgrade Tag needs to be removed. worked after that. But this setup forces us to keep the Product Version always same? Because if I change product version, It does not uninstall the previous version but instead installs the new version. So now I can see 2 versions installed. Product Version no helps to identify which build is installed on users machine.

Comment: Do i need to remove UpgradeCode tag in Product ?